# Getting country name from country code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce defines countries as follows (edited for brevity):

```
class WC_Countries {
    public $countries;

    public function __construct() {
        global $woocommerce, $states;

        $this->countries = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_countries', array(
            'AF' => __( 'Afghanistan', 'woocommerce' ),
            'AX' => __( '&#197;land Islands', 'woocommerce' ),
            'AL' => __( 'Albania', 'woocommerce' ),
            'DZ' => __( 'Algeria', 'woocommerce' ),
            // […]
        ));
    }
}
```

When an order is placed, the country code is written to the WordPress `wp_postmeta` table and can be extracted anywhere an order id can be accessed using the `get_post_meta()` function:

```
get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_country', true ),
```

Since we are simply retrieving two characters from the database, the question is how to translate the shipping country code (e.g. `AF`) to the country name specified in the `WC_Countries` class?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can access the `WC_Countries` class with `WC()->countries`. So to get the country name from an order, you must use:

```php
WC()->countries->countries[ $order->shipping_country ];
```

On WooCommerce 3.0+ you should use:

```php
WC()->countries->countries[ $order->get_shipping_country() ];
```

If you like to get the state, you need before check if exist, since WooCommerce doesn't include all states, so here what do you need:

```php
$states = WC()->countries->get_states( $order->get_shipping_country() );
$state  = ! empty( $states[ $order->get_shipping_state() ] ) ? $states[ $order->get_shipping_state() ] : '';
```

Comment: And how to get country name in specific language? For example sk_SK?

Comment: Neat solution, just want to mention its recommend to use `WC()->countries->get_countries()` to get the country array

Answer (score 9):

To get the state name from state code you can use.

```
WC()->countries->states[$order->billing_country][$order->billing_state];
```

Comment: Great addition.  I will add this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
global $woocommerce;
$shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking **how to get the Woocommerce shop base address**, not the cart or an order address, and this thread comes in many Google keywords related to the topic.
I came accross the following answer which I updated a little :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334608/177690

```
private static function afg_getBaseAddressData() {
    return array(
        'address' => WC()->countries->get_base_address(),
        'address-2' => WC()->countries->get_base_address_2(),
        'city' => WC()->countries->get_base_city(),
        'zip' => WC()->countries->get_base_postcode(),
        'state' => WC()->countries->get_base_state(),
        'country' => WC()->countries->countries[WC()->countries->get_base_country()],
        'mail' => self::afg_getPublicMail()
    );
}

private static function afg_getPublicMail() {
    //replace by the way you get an email address
    return filter_var(get_option('address-public-mail'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

public static function afg_getAddressTemplate() {
    $datas = apply_filters( 'afg_shop_base_address', self::afg_getBaseAddressData() );
    $html = '';

    $html .= '<address>'; 
    foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
        if($data) {
            $html .= '<p class="address-line '.$key.'">'.$data.'</p>';
        }
    }
    $html .= '</address>';

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function a000_remove_bundles_counting(){
//////////////////////////////
global $woocommerce_bundles;
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',
array( $woocommerce_bundles->display, 'woo_bundles_cart_contents_count' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'a000_remove_bundles_counting' );
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function d000_cart_contents_count( $count ) {
    global $woocommerce;
 $cat_check = false;
  foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { //foreach

 $product = $cart_item['data'];

 if ( has_term( 'VIP', 'product_tag', $product->id ) ) {//search product_cat
$cat_check = true;
// break because we only need one "true" to matter here
if (!function_exists('woo_override_checkout_fields')) {
function woo_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) { // woo_override_checkout_fields Function


$fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'label' => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
'options' => array('US' => 'United States(US)')
); 

$fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'label' => __('State', 'woocommerce'),
'options' => array('CA' => 'California(CA)')

);

return $fields; 
} //end woo_override_checkout_fields Function
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'woo_override_checkout_fields' );

} // end search product_cat 
  }// end foreach



return $count;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count',
'd000_cart_contents_count' );
```

First you have set product tag "VIP or what ever you like and then you will add it to code

```
if ( has_term( 'VIP', 'product_tag', $product->id ) ) {//search product_cat 

    $cat_check = true;
}
```

> in this function looking is there any product with "VIP" Product tag.
>   and `$cat_check = true;`
>
> then inside this in function we adding function
>   `woo_override_checkout_fields( $fields )` function to set limited
>   country as shipping country field.
>
> Inside `woo_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) { }`
>
> Set which country you want to show

```
$fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'label' => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
'options' => array('US' => 'United States(US)')
);



$fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(
'type' => 'select',
'label' => __('State', 'woocommerce'),
'options' => array('CA' => 'California(CA)')

);
```