# Woocommerce order checkout to whatsapp

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, whatsapp, checkout

i want to make a custom checkout system that redirect order details to whatsapp using this code: (PS, i got it from solusipress.com)

```
class SolusiPress_WA_Checkout {

protected $version = '0.9.2';
protected $wa_number = '62xxxxxxx';
protected $resend_text = 'Click here if your browser not redirect to WhatsApp';
protected $wa_message_template = <<<EOT
Halo kak, 

Berikut pesanan saya, mohon segera diproses

*Nama:* {{first_name}} {{last_name}}
*Telepon:* {{phone}}
*Alamat Kirim:* {{address_1}} {{address_2}} {{city}} {{state}}
*Catatan:*
{{note}}

-----------------------------------------
{{woo-orderdetail}}     
EOT;

public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', array( $this, 'wc_prevent_submission' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_wa-checkout', array( $this, 'whatsapp_checkout' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wa-checkout', array( $this, 'whatsapp_checkout' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( $this, 'checkout_order_processed' ), 50, 3 );                
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', array( $this, 'set_shipping_fields' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_template_part', array( $this, 'resend_wa_link' ), 10, 4 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', array( $this, 'resend_wa_link_thankyou' ), 10, 1 );
}   

public function enqueue_scripts() {
    $uri = home_url( '/wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/' );
    wp_register_script( 'woo-whatsapp-checkout', $uri . 'whatsapp-checkout.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version );
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css' );   
    if( is_checkout() ) { 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
        wp_localize_script( 'woo-whatsapp-checkout', 'solusipress', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( '/admin-ajax.php' ),
            'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'solusipress-woo-checkout-wa' )
        ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'woo-whatsapp-checkout' );           
    }
}   

public function wc_prevent_submission($data, $errors) {
    if ( isset($_POST['spwoo_prevent_submit']) && empty( $errors->errors ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'theme', __( 'go_whatsapp_redirect', 'woocommerce' ) );
    } 
}

public function whatsapp_checkout() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'solusipress-woo-checkout-wa', 'security' );
    $checkout = WC_Checkout::instance();
    $checkout->process_checkout();
}   

public function checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) { 
    $wa_send_number = $this->wa_number;        
    $customer = array(
        'billing' => $this->set_address( $posted_data ),
        'shipping' => $this->set_address( $posted_data, 'shipping' )
    );
        $fields = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'email', 'phone', 'note', 'city', 'district', 'state' );
    $wa_message = $this->wa_message_template;
    if( $wa_message != '' ) {
        foreach( $fields as $f ) {
            if( $f == 'note' ) {
                $wa_message = str_replace( "{{note}}", $posted_data['order_comments'], $wa_message );
            } else {
                $__text = '';
                if( isset( $customer['billing'][$f] ) ) { $__text = $customer['billing'][$f]; }
                $wa_message = str_replace( "{{".$f."}}", $__text, $wa_message );
            }
        }
    }
    $_wa_message = $this->checkout_whatsapp_message();
    if( $_wa_message != '' ) {
        $wa_message = str_replace( "{{woo-orderdetail}}", $_wa_message, $wa_message );
    }
    $redirect_url = '';
    if( $order ) {
        $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
        if( WC()->cart->needs_payment() && $payment_method != 'cod' && $payment_method != 'bacs' ) {
            $redirect_url = $order->get_checkout_payment_url();
            $wa_message .= "\n\n";
            $wa_message .= 'Informasi pembayaran ' . $redirect_url;
        } else {
            $redirect_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
        }            
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        WC()->session->set('cart', array());    
    }            
    $return = array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'to_number' => $wa_send_number,
        'wa_message' => urlencode( $wa_message ),
        'redirect' => $redirect_url
    );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_to_number', $wa_send_number );
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_message', urlencode( $wa_message ) );
    echo json_encode( $return );
    die();
}

public function set_shipping_fields( $data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( substr( $key, 0, 8 ) == 'billing_' ) {
            $fld = str_replace( 'billing_', '', $key );
            if( !isset( $data[ 'shipping_' . $fld ] ) ) {
                $data[ 'shipping_' . $fld ] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

private function set_address( $data, $context='billing' ) {
    $address_fields = array(
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'company',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'address_1',
        'address_2',
        'district',
        'city',
        'postcode',
        'state',
        'country',
    );
    $address = array();
    foreach( $address_fields as $field ) {
        if( isset( $data[ $context . '_' . $field ] ) ) {
            $address[ $field ] = $data[ $context.'_'.$field ];               
        }
    }
    return $address;            
}

private function checkout_whatsapp_message(){
    $cart = $this->get_cart_items();
    $shippings = $this->get_shippings();
    $txt = '';
    if( !empty( $cart['items'] ) ) {
        foreach( $cart['items'] as $item ){
            if( $txt != '' ) $txt .= "\n";
            if( isset( $item['sku'] ) && trim($item['sku']) != '' ) {
                if( $txt != '' ) $txt .= "\n";
                $txt .= "SKU: " . $item['sku'];
            }
            $txt .= "\n"."*".$item['name']."*";
            if( !empty( $item['variations'] ) ) {
                $txt .= ' - ';
                $variations = '';
                foreach( $item['variations'] as $v ) {
                    if( $variations != '' ) $variations .= ', ';
                    $variations .= $v['key'].': '.$v['value'];
                }
                $txt .= $variations;
            }            
            $txt .= "\n";
            $txt .= ' @ ' . $this->wc_price( $item['price'] );
            $txt .= ' x ' . $item['quantity'] . ' => ' . 
                    $this->wc_price( $item['price']*$item['quantity'] );
        }
        $txt .= "\n";
        $txt .= "-----------------------------------------"."\n";
        $txt .= "*Subtotal* " . $this->wc_price( $cart['subtotal'] );
        $txt .= "\n"."-----------------------------------------";
        
        if( !empty( $cart['coupons']  ) ){
            foreach ( $cart['coupons'] as $c ){
                $txt .= "\n";
                $txt .= '*' . __( 'Coupon: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $c['code'] . '* ' . $this->wc_price( $c['amount'] );
            }       
        }
    }
    if( $shippings['total'] > 0 ) {
        $txt .= "\n";
        $txt .= "*Shipping*";        
        foreach( $shippings['lines'] as $s ) {
            $txt .= "\n";
            $txt .= $s['label'] . ' ' . $this->wc_price( $s['cost']+$s['tax_cost'] );
        }
        $txt .= "\n";
        $txt .= $shippings['address'];
    } else {
        $txt .= "\n";
        $txt .= "*Shipping*";   
        $txt .= "\n";
        $txt .= "Total price exclude shipping fee.";
    }
    
    $txt .= "\n";
    $txt .= "-----------------------------------------"."\n";
    $txt .= "*TOTAL* " . $this->wc_price( WC()->cart->total );
    $txt .= "\n"."-----------------------------------------";
    
    $txt = str_replace( "&nbsp;"," ", $txt );
    return $txt;    
}   

private function get_resend_wa_link( $order_id ){
    $to_number = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_to_number', true );
    $message = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_message', true );
    $displayed = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_resend_link_display', true );
    if( $displayed != 'yes' ) {
        if( $message != '' ) {
            $link_url = 'https://wa.me/'.$to_number.'?text=' . $message;
            $link_text = $this->resend_text;
            echo '<p class="woo-resend-whatsapp"><a href="'.$link_url.'" target="_blank"><strong><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> '. $link_text .'</strong></a></p>';
        }
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'order_wa_resend_link_display', 'yes' );
    }
}

public function resend_wa_link_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    echo $this->get_resend_wa_link( $order_id );
}

public function resend_wa_link( $name, $path, $located, $args ) {
    if( $name == 'checkout/form-pay.php' ) {
        $order_id = $args['order']->get_id();
        echo $this->get_resend_wa_link( $order_id );
    }
}       

private function wc_price( $price, $args=array() ) {
    $args = apply_filters(
        'woo_custom_wc_price_args',
        wp_parse_args(
          $args,
          array(
            'ex_tax_label'       => false,
            'currency'           => '',
            'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
            'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
            'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
            'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
          )
        )
    );
    $unformatted_price = $price;
    $negative          = $price < 0;
    $price             = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
    $price             = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] ), $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] );
    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $args['decimals'] > 0 ) {
        $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
    }
    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'],  get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ), $price );
    $return          = $formatted_price;
    if ( $args['ex_tax_label'] && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
        $return .= WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat();
    }   
    return apply_filters( 'woo_custom_wc_price', $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price );  
    return $price;
}   

private function get_cart_items() {
    $return = array(
        'items' => array(),
        'coupons' => array(),
        'subtotal' => 0,
    );  
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    if( !empty( $cart_items ) ) {       
        foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {  
            $product = new WC_product( $item['product_id'] );
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            $variation_id = null;
            $product_var = null;
            $product_type = $product->get_type();
            $name = $product->get_name();        
            $item_meta = [];
            if( isset( $item['variation_id'] ) && $item['variation_id'] != '' ) {
                $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $item['variation_id'] );
                $product_var = $item['variation'];
                $product_type = $variation->get_type();
                foreach( $product_var as $k => $v ) {
                    $_k = str_replace('attribute_', '', $k);
                    $_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $v, $_k );
                    if( $_term ) {
                        $label = wc_attribute_label( $_term->taxonomy, $product );
                        array_push( $item_meta, [
                            'key' => $label,
                            'value' => $_term->name,
                        ] );
                    } else {
                        $label = wc_attribute_label( $_k, $product );
                        array_push( $item_meta, [
                            'key' => $label,
                            'value' => $v
                        ] );
                    }
                }
                $variation_id = $variation->get_id();
                $name = $variation->get_title();
                $weight = $variation->get_weight();
                $sku = $variation->get_sku();
                $price = $variation->get_price();
                $price_html = $variation->get_price_html();
                $attributes = $item['variation'];
            } else {
                $weight = $product->get_weight();    
                $sku = $product->get_sku();
                $price = $product->get_price();
                $price_html = $product->get_price_html();
            }
            array_push( $return['items'], array(
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'product_type' => $product_type,
                'variation_id' => $variation_id,
                'name' => $name,
                'sku' => $sku,
                'weight' => $weight,
                'price' => $price,
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                'product_var' => $product_var,
                'variations' => $item_meta          
            ) );                
        }       
    }
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if( $subtotal > 0 ) {
        $return['subtotal'] = $subtotal;
    }
    $coupons = WC()->cart->coupon_discount_totals;
    if( !empty( $coupons ) ) {
        foreach ( $coupons as $code => $amount ){
            array_push( $return['coupons'], array(
                'code' => $code,
                'amount' => $amount,
            ) );
        }   
    }
    return $return;
}

private function get_shippings(){
    $customer = WC()->session->get( 'customer' );   
    $cart_totals = WC()->session->get( 'cart_totals' );
    $shipping_total = $cart_totals['shipping_total'];       
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $return = array(
        'lines' => array(),
        'address' => array(),
        'total' => $shipping_total
    );
    $shipping_dest = null;
    $package_id = '0';
    if ( WC()->session->__isset( 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_id ) ) {
        $pckg = WC()->session->get( 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_id );
        foreach( $pckg['rates'] as $shipping_rate_id => $shipping_rate ){
            if( in_array( $shipping_rate_id, $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
                $label_name  = $shipping_rate->get_label();
                $cost = $shipping_rate->get_cost();
                $tax_cost    = $shipping_rate->get_shipping_tax();
                array_push( $return['lines'], array(
                    'label' => $label_name,
                    'cost' => $cost,
                    'tax_cost' => $tax_cost
                ) );
                $shipping_dest = $package['destination'];
            }
        }
    }
    $_addr = '';
    $address_parts = array(
        'city' => '',
        'address_2' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
    );
    if( !is_null( $shipping_dest ) ) {
        $_addr = $shipping_dest['city'];
        if( $_addr != '' ) $_addr .= ', ';
        $_addr .= $shipping_dest['address_2'];
        if( $_addr != '' ) $_addr .= ' ';
        $_addr .= $shipping_dest['postcode'];
    } else {
        if( isset( $customer['city'] ) && $customer['city'] != '' ) {
            $address_parts['city'] = $customer['city'];
            $_addr = $customer['city'];
        }
        if( isset( $customer['address_2'] ) && $customer['address_2'] != '' ) {
            $address_parts['address_2'] = $customer['address_2'];
            if( $_addr != '' ) $_addr .= ', ';
            $_addr .= $customer['address_2'];
        }
        if( isset( $customer['postcode'] ) && $customer['postcode'] != '' ) {
            $address_parts['postcode'] = $customer['postcode'];
            if( $_addr != '' ) $_addr .= ' ';
            $_addr .= $customer['postcode'];
        }
    }
    $return['address'] = $_addr;
    $return['address_parts'] = $address_parts;
    return $return;
    print_r($address_parts);
    }   
}
new SolusiPress_WA_Checkout();
```

and my website using dropdown for `province`, `city`, and `district` fields. But when it comes to the whatsapp message, [like this whatsapp message sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Y1U.png) *(note: 50 and 10 is the IDs for city and district)* the field is only showing the city ID for every city. Please help, how do I make it display the city name instead of the ID?

Note: Alamat is Address in Indonesian

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528454/getting-country-name-from-country-code-in-woocommerce

Comment: @mujuonly can u help me, where should i put the code in code snippets, i just want to print the city name that appear in the form, but it keep showing the ID in whatsapp message